# When validate function is being called in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, validation

I am trying to figure out which methods are calling validate() function of Validator interface so that I do not manually call the function (if any of them). However, I wasn't able to find proper documentation if the following methods are calling validate() function or not.

I am guessing the following functions calls the validate() function:

```
Session.save() 
Session.update() 
Session.saveOrUpdate()
```

(Session is a Hibernate Session)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these methods trigger a validation. [The documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/#validator-checkconstraints-orm) says:

> Whenever a PreInsertEvent, PreUpdateEvent or PreDeleteEvent occurs, the listener will verify all constraints of the entity instance and throw an exception if any constraint is violated. Per default objects will be checked before any inserts or updates are made by Hibernate. Pre deletion events will per default not trigger a validation.

So the validation will happen at flush time, just before Hibernate inserts or updates an entity in the database.